# Nginx Ingress Controller - Failed to watch *v1.EndpointSlice:

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have deployed Nginx Ingress Controller in EKS cluster v1.20.15-eks using helm chart from https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx/ version 4.4.2

The controller is deployed successfully but when creating Ingress Object I am getting below error.

```
W0206 09:46:11.909381       8 reflector.go:424] k8s.io/client-go@v0.25.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: failed to list *v1.EndpointSlice: the server could not find the requested resource
E0206 09:46:11.909410       8 reflector.go:140] k8s.io/client-go@v0.25.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: Failed to watch *v1.EndpointSlice: failed to list *v1.EndpointSlice: the server could not find the requested resource
```

kubectl version is

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.0", GitCommit:"af46c47ce925f4c4ad5cc8d1fca46c7b77d13b38", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-08T17:59:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20+", GitVersion:"v1.20.15-eks-fb459a0", GitCommit:"165a4903196b688886b456054e6a5d72ba8cddf4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-10-24T20:31:58Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Can anyone help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chart version 4.4.2 has the application version of 1.5.1.

Version 1.5.1 of nginx only supports kubernetes versions of 1.25, 1.24, 1.23.
For kubernetes v1.20 the latest supported version was v1.3.1.

The chart version for v1.3.1 is v4.2.5.

The error you are facing, is due to nginx not finding v1.EndpointSlice, since the EndpointSlice was GA on k8s v1.21 as can be seen [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/endpoint-slices/). In previous versions it would be running on alpha/beta not v1.

Please refer to the [table here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx#supported-versions-table).